# Python and json issue

Tags: python, json

I have problem for decoding json format.

Here's my data.

```
20110312010116730|{"place":{"country_code":"US","url":"http:\/\/api.twitter.com\/1\/geo\/id\/9fbe124c83c364fe.json","bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-78.894441,35.03811699],[-78.85501596,35.03811699],[-78.85501596,35.08142904],[-78.894441,35.08142904]]]},"place_type":"neighborhood","name":"Downtown Fayetteville","country":"United States","attributes":{},"id":"9fbe124c83c364fe","full_name":"Downtown Fayetteville, Fayetteville"},"user":{"is_translator":false,"listed_count":9,"statuses_count":3695,"profile_link_color":"9ede14","url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/nicholasd.whitehead","following":null,"verified":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"a7ed11","contributors_enabled":false,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":354,"profile_background_color":"131516","description":" #TEAMDROID #TAURUS #TEAMRATCHET #TEAMFITTEDS !!!! \u2752Single \u2752Taken \u2714SLiCK","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a2.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/213719493\/lime_green_logo.jpg","created_at":"Thu Jun 18 21:07:16 +0000 2009","protected":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1263451862\/my_shirt_off_normal.jpg","follow_request_sent":null,"time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)","favourites_count":3,"profile_text_color":"b6e82c","location":"from the 252 to the 910","name":"\u015bl\u00ef\u00e7k \u0148\u00ef\u00e7k","show_all_inline_media":false,"geo_enabled":true,"notifications":null,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"080808","screen_name":"infamous_SLiCK","id":48490066,"id_str":"48490066","lang":"en","profile_background_tile":true,"utc_offset":-18000,"followers_count":224},"coordinates":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-78.883968,35.052185]},"text":"i dont even know who Sam & Ronnie is !!","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"truncated":false,"source":"\u003Ca href=\"http:\/\/twidroyd.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003Etwidroyd\u003C\/a\u003E","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"created_at":"Sat Mar 12 06:01:16 +0000 2011","in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"geo":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[35.052185,-78.883968]},"contributors":null,"retweeted":false,"id":46450665555378176,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"id_str":"46450665555378176","entities":{"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"hashtags":[]},"retweet_count":0}
```

I have more that 200GB data for text like this.

Here's my code.

```
tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r").readlines()
for i,line in enumerate(tweets_file):
if i%2 is 0:
    temp = line.split('|')
    tweet = json.loads(temp[1])
    #tweets_data.append(tweet)
```

Here's my question.
I tried to decode them. but fail.
At first, I though the number very first in the data make the error.
So I tried to seperate the number and json data.
But it still doesn't work.
Because something different just appear in my list.
Like this:

```
['20110312015935803', '{"place":{"country_code":"US","url":"http:\\/\\/api.twitter.com\\/1\\/geo\\/id\\/a1f2dacd80a51287.json","bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-73.002796,42.990631],[-72.866051,42.990631],[-72.866051,43.119106],[-73.002796,43.119106]]]},"place_type":"city","name":"Stratton","country":"United States","attributes":{},"id":"a1f2dacd80a51287","full_name":"Stratton, VT"},"user":{"follow_request_sent":null,"show_all_inline_media":false,"geo_enabled":true,"profile_link_color":"546080","url":"http:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/br.vivizanatta","following":null,"verified":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"bcc7e3","is_translator":false,"listed_count":0,"statuses_count":330,"profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_background_color":"2d313f","description":"Stay up to date with news, photos, videos, blog, bio and more from the brazilian journalist and photographer Vivian Zanatta.","contributors_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\\/\\/a2.twimg.com\\/profile_background_images\\/211883639\\/aspen1_829_49514.jpg","created_at":"Sat Jul 10 15:05:48 +0000 2010","friends_count":79,"protected":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\\/\\/a2.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1259071695\\/VIVI_DDH7912_normal.jpg","time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)","favourites_count":0,"profile_text_color":"537de6","location":"Washington, DC, USA","name":"Vivi Zanatta \\u2714","notifications":null,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"191e2a","screen_name":"vivizanatta_","id":165082798,"id_str":"165082798","lang":"en","profile_background_tile":false,"utc_offset":-18000,"followers_count":83},"coordinates":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-72.9053683,43.1134486]},"text":"I\'m at Stratton Mountain Ski Resort (5 Village Lodge Rd, Stratton Mountain) http:\\/\\/4sq.com\\/i3ULvp","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"truncated":false,"source":"\\u003Ca href=\\"http:\\/\\/foursquare.com\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\"\\u003Efoursquare\\u003C\\/a\\u003E","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"created_at":"Sat Mar 12 06:59:35 +0000 2011","in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"geo":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[43.1134486,-72.9053683]},"contributors":null,"retweeted":false,"id":46465342800797698,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"id_str":"46465342800797698","entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"indices":[76,97],"url":"http:\\/\\/4sq.com\\/i3ULvp","expanded_url":null}],"user_mentions":[]},"retweet_count":0}\n']
['\n']
```

Suddenly ['\n'] appears.
well I guess because lines are seperated by two ['\n'].
Anyway, when I use partition,

```
('20110312015935977', '|', '{"place":{"country_code":"US","url":"http:\\/\\/api.twitter.com\\/1\\/geo\\/id\\/b8b87894eb3d7849.json","bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-95.542521,29.670631],[-95.492419,29.670631],[-95.492419,29.694855],[-95.542521,29.694855]]]},"place_type":"neighborhood","name":"Braeburn","country":"United States","attributes":{},"id":"b8b87894eb3d7849","full_name":"Braeburn, Houston"},"user":{"profile_link_color":"ed0909","url":null,"following":null,"verified":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"f00505","follow_request_sent":null,"show_all_inline_media":true,"geo_enabled":true,"profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_background_color":"61b8c2","description":"#TeamPlaystation #TeamLRG #TeamAquarius and #PvNation .It bring me great pleasure to welcome the real and banish the Fake...","is_translator":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\\/\\/a2.twimg.com\\/profile_background_images\\/179334599\\/screwston7jsredc.jpg","listed_count":0,"statuses_count":163,"created_at":"Wed Dec 08 04:04:16 +0000 2010","protected":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\\/\\/a0.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1256895503\\/image_normal.jpg","time_zone":"Central America","favourites_count":2,"profile_text_color":"fa0505","location":"Houston, Tx","name":"Craig Irving","contributors_enabled":false,"notifications":null,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"020303","screen_name":"xxMinion","id":224098461,"id_str":"224098461","lang":"en","profile_background_tile":true,"utc_offset":-21600,"friends_count":36,"followers_count":35},"coordinates":null,"text":"If your White or Mexican #WhoSaidItWasOk to say \\"whats up my nigga\\" and then call your homeboys the word Nigga lol","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"truncated":false,"source":"web","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"created_at":"Sat Mar 12 06:59:35 +0000 2011","in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"geo":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted":false,"id":46465343463505920,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"id_str":"46465343463505920","entities":{"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"hashtags":[{"indices":[25,40],"text":"WhoSaidItWasOk"}]},"retweet_count":0}\n')
('\n', '', '')
```

It appears.

oh and my data's format is gz.
How can I read on python without decompressing?

Comment: Ohhh the error says that ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 664 (char 663).
Sorry. It was really 11 pm in Korea.. I was so tired so forget it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are `|` in your data, `split` splits too much and the `json` string is truncated

You can use `maxsplit` parameter

```
temp = line.split('|',1)
```

or `partition`:

```
temp = line.partition('|')
```

(use `temp[2]` in that case because separator is also returned)

If you have further problems, consider adding a `try/except` block for each line so you can narrow down the problem.

EDIT: also added protection against blank lines as a follow up to your edit.

```
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for i,line in enumerate(tweets_file):
    if i%2 == 0:
       try:
          data = line.partition('|')[2]
          if data:        
              tweet = json.loads(data)
       except ValueError as e:
          print("Cannot parse '{}'".format(data)
          print("Error line {}: {}".format(i+1,str(e)))
```

Comment: The problem is, when I seperate them, something else just pop up everytime. I just deleted '|', and then lists appear: the number and json format list/ "\n" list. These two lists appear again and again.
when I delete '\n', then suddenly " '' " appears. It makes me crazy

Comment: @YooInhyeok Don't panic, _isolate_ an issue first.

Comment: @YooInhyeok check my edit, should help making your code more robust and isolate the problematic line(s)

Comment: Hi. It's morning in Korea. I'm calm now.
The problem is clear.
I show you the result above.

Comment: Just skip the lines partitionned to "", that's it. And I'm replying quicky to your gz question (since it's something else): lookup for `gzopen` which does exactly what you want. lots of examples here on SO.

Comment: "Check the edit" means "reload the page, something was changed in the answer since last time you looked".  You can also click the "edited xxx ago" to see a diff of what exactly was changed.

Comment: @tripleee _that_ was useful. I never had the idea of clicking on the "edited" link.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 
Sorry for late.
I don't understand... you mean delete all | , \n and ""?
For now, I just handled them by exception.
I can't clearly understand. Why the \n, "" appear?
I just splited them and just they pop up.
And it's for loop line by line. The line can't be changed when I delete something inside the loop. Why does it happen?

Comment: `if data:` filters out empty data. when partition returns empty string, it's not parsed by your code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Okay. But it still doesn't work. It says ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Oh and more. I have more than 30 thousand gz files.
Can I read them more easily? I mean there's a way to read all files in directory or whole file. Cus.. I can't open each one of them cus these are really a lot of files.

Comment: I have added another `print("Cannot parse '{}'".format(data)` in the exception. Can you retry and post the error?

Comment: you're not opening the .gz files directly are you? at least you used `gzopen` right?

Comment: It says Error line 2: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
and the line increase by 2n: 2, 4 , 6,  8, ...

Comment: No.. I didn't use it yet. Okay then I use it first. then ask you. thx.
Now I'm going to some meeting with my professor... so I'll back later

Comment: Well I had some issues but I solved it. Never mind that.

Comment: Is it working now? When it does you ll be able to accept the answer.

Comment: Ahh.. I meant I solved the issue about reading every 2 other lines.
I clear my issue and reposted again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643238/python-json-error-valueerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0