# python json error: ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I'm from Korea, so probably you don't understand clearly.

I have a issue about loading json file via python.

```
with open("D:/twitter/salathe-us-twitter/20110312/SB_DATA_SB/tweets.txt.2011-03-12_01", encoding='UTF8') as f:
for line in f:
    temp = line.partition('|')
    date.append(temp[0])  # date
    tweets_data.append(temp[2])
```

Here's my python code.
I seperate the line because there're some errors.

The temp looks like:

```
('20110302141002236', '|', '{"user":{"following":null,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\\/\\/a3.twimg.com\\/profile_background_images\\/141128439\\/2010-07-01_15.33.10.jpg","favourites_count":1,"verified":false,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","profile_text_color":"333333","follow_request_sent":null,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","id_str":"173736821","profile_background_tile":false,"followers_count":19,"created_at":"Mon Aug 02 06:37:45 +0000 2010","description":"Attend CWU and just tryna do me.","is_translator":false,"show_all_inline_media":false,"geo_enabled":true,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","location":"Tacoma, WA","listed_count":1,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","protected":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\\/\\/a3.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1208687030\\/Twitter_normal.jpg","lang":"en","name":"Quintin Brown","contributors_enabled":false,"statuses_count":340,"notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"screen_name":"QBrown15","id":173736821,"utc_offset":-28800,"friends_count":48,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","url":"http:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/#!\\/profile.php?id=1195837597"},"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"contributors":null,"coordinates":null,"retweeted":false,"text":"\\"RT @barr253 I love fat asses. #honesttweet\\" &lt;&lt;&lt; Naw, that\'s an #ObviousTweet","in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"retweet_count":0,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"id_str":"43025281954480130","source":"web","created_at":"Wed Mar 02 19:10:01 +0000 2011","truncated":false,"entities":{"user_mentions":[{"indices":[4,12],"id_str":"204626247","name":"John Barr","screen_name":"barr253","id":204626247}],"urls":[],"hashtags":[{"indices":[31,43],"text":"honesttweet"},{"indices":[73,86],"text":"ObviousTweet"}]},"geo":null,"place":{"bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-120.597461,46.966947],[-120.518162,46.966947],[-120.518162,47.029281],[-120.597461,47.029281]]]},"place_type":"city","name":"Ellensburg","country":"United States","attributes":{},"id":"c95cdb2a983262e5","full_name":"Ellensburg, WA","country_code":"US","url":"http:\\/\\/api.twitter.com\\/1\\/geo\\/id\\/c95cdb2a983262e5.json"},"favorited":false,"id":43025281954480130}\n')
('\n', '', '')
```

You can see ('\n', '', ''). That's why I partition them.

So I tried to put temp[2] to parameter of json.loads().

But it says

```
C:\Python34\python.exe D:/Twitter_project/TEST.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Twitter_project/TEST.py", line 5, in <module>
a = json.loads(temp[2])
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What's the problem of my code?
The data isn't json format?

So now, I'm just using try, exception to read the data for temporary.

It worked. But I want to know why it happen and how to fix it.

Here's my try except code:

```
import json
date = []
tweets_data = []
with open("D:/twitter/salathe-us-       twitter/20110302/SB_DATA_SB/tweets.txt.2011-03-02_14-05", encoding='UTF8') as f:
for i,line in enumerate(f):
    try:
        temp = line.partition('|')
        date.append(temp[0])
        tweet = json.loads(temp[2])
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first i have tried that you have valid JSON format according this [validator](http://jsonlint.com/) and you have.

Then i have tried to write same code and the following code works fine for me withnout any exceptions.

```
import json

temp = ('20110302141002236', '|', '{"user":{"following":null,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\\/\\/a3.twimg.com\\/profile_background_images\\/141128439\\/2010-07-01_15.33.10.jpg","favourites_count":1,"verified":false,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","profile_text_color":"333333","follow_request_sent":null,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","id_str":"173736821","profile_background_tile":false,"followers_count":19,"created_at":"Mon Aug 02 06:37:45 +0000 2010","description":"Attend CWU and just tryna do me.","is_translator":false,"show_all_inline_media":false,"geo_enabled":true,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","location":"Tacoma, WA","listed_count":1,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","protected":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\\/\\/a3.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1208687030\\/Twitter_normal.jpg","lang":"en","name":"Quintin Brown","contributors_enabled":false,"statuses_count":340,"notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"screen_name":"QBrown15","id":173736821,"utc_offset":-28800,"friends_count":48,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","url":"http:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/#!\\/profile.php?id=1195837597"},"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"contributors":null,"coordinates":null,"retweeted":false,"text":"\\"RT @barr253 I love fat asses. #honesttweet\\" &lt;&lt;&lt; Naw, that\'s an #ObviousTweet","in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"retweet_count":0,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"id_str":"43025281954480130","source":"web","created_at":"Wed Mar 02 19:10:01 +0000 2011","truncated":false,"entities":{"user_mentions":[{"indices":[4,12],"id_str":"204626247","name":"John Barr","screen_name":"barr253","id":204626247}],"urls":[],"hashtags":[{"indices":[31,43],"text":"honesttweet"},{"indices":[73,86],"text":"ObviousTweet"}]},"geo":null,"place":{"bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-120.597461,46.966947],[-120.518162,46.966947],[-120.518162,47.029281],[-120.597461,47.029281]]]},"place_type":"city","name":"Ellensburg","country":"United States","attributes":{},"id":"c95cdb2a983262e5","full_name":"Ellensburg, WA","country_code":"US","url":"http:\\/\\/api.twitter.com\\/1\\/geo\\/id\\/c95cdb2a983262e5.json"},"favorited":false,"id":43025281954480130}\n')
('\n', '', '')

a = json.loads(temp[2])
```

Tested on Python 3.5, 3.3

Comment: No... you just typing and put json format in the variable.

Comment: What? You wrote you ve got exception on `json.loads(temp[2])` which means the parsing of JSON failed but I used same data as you and there is no exception

Comment: Oh I meant that I already did the same thing. I forgot to writing it.
Yeap. When you just put string format to json.load(), it worked with the data. But when I just read them on python, it just doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "just read them on python"? Btw `json.load()` and `json.loads()` are two different methods! The output of `json.loads()` method are dictionaries and you can access it as standard dictionary.

Comment: And 'read them on' meant that I read them by open method or readline function. Not input as string like you did, literally just 'read' on python. See the temp variable what I wrote. I approach it as reading file, but you just set it tuple. I'm not sure u r clear.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its from file or database or whatever else, no? The temp variables are same on my and your side. Original question is that you have got exception in parsing of temp, i tried same temp variable as you and there is no exception. Am I wrong with something?

Comment: Oh.. That's really what I want to ask and solve.... You just repeat what the problem is. you didn't solve anything or advise me at all. you just repeat what my problem is which is I knew already, and want to fix. Didn't blame you but I guess there's misunderstanding.

Comment: Here's clear one. My issue is that json.loads didn't work by reading file method. But it work when I put the parameter as string format.
Same data, different parameter format. That's the problem.
And.. precisely not different parameter at all. Both are string. It just matter of I read the data on or not.

Comment: But method `json.loads()` only accept a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document. From this: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html. Maybe you are looking for `json.load()`

Comment: json.load() also didnt' work. It said 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read''

Comment: Why you cant simple read file into string and then parse string as you did in previous example with `tweet = json.loads(temp[2])`?

Comment: What?
As I said, It didn't work. And I don't know why. That's why I post the problem

Comment: Seriously you should update your question... As i said several days ago... this workes for me without any exception... So i cant help you. You provided us with wrong temp data or something...